# CoreData UINavigationController managedObjectContext Error

Tags: core-data, uinavigationcontroller, ios6, uitabbarcontroller

I have a project that include a combined tabbarController and navigation controller.
sorry,becauce i can't post image, the link of image here:

http://s12.postimage.org/58lbzzxm5/Screen_Shot_2012_11_10_at_9_56_07_AM.png

Code Of NAppDelegate.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface NAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator     *persistentStoreCoordinator;

- (void)saveContext;
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory;

@end
```

Code Of NAppDelegate.m:

```
#import "NAppDelegate.h"
#import "TVC_TabProvince.h"

@implementation NAppDelegate
@synthesize managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;
@synthesize managedObjectModel = _managedObjectModel;
@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = _persistentStoreCoordinator;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;

    NSArray *arrController = [tabBarController viewControllers];
    TVC_TabProvince *controller = (TVC_TabProvince*) [arrController objectAtIndex:0];
    controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

    return YES;
}
```

Before adding the navigation controller, it run without any problem. But when I add this, an error appear:

```
error:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-
[UINavigationController setManagedObjectContext:]: unrecognized selector sent to
instance 0x74b26b0'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
TVC_TabProvince *controller = (TVC_TabProvince*) [arrController objectAtIndex:0];
```

`[arrController objectAtIndex:0]` is the first view controller of the tab bar controller, so this is the *navigation controller* and not the `TVC_TabProvince` controller. The type cast `(TVC_TabProvince *)` does not change the object, it is still a navigation controller.

So you have to add one step:

```
NSArray *arrController = [tabBarController viewControllers];
UINavigationController *navController = [arrController objectAtIndex:0];
TVC_TabProvince *controller = [navController. viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

It might be more flexible to go the other way around: Instead of "pushing" the managed object context from the application delegate to the table view controller, you "pull" it from the table view controller when needed. So somewhere in "TVC_TabProvince.m" you do

```
NAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
self.context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
```

Then it does not matter anymore where the table view controller is in the view controller hierarchy. (But that is only a suggestion.)